# como agrego a un arreglo palabras separadas por letras

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())


matrix =[]
for i in range(n):
   matrix.append([])
   for e in range(m):
      matrix[i].append("")
```

asì hago mi arreglo

ahora quiero agregarle letras en cada posición como puedo hacerlo.

**Ejemplo:**

entrada

> asd
>
> dsa
>
> qwe

salida

> [['a', 's', 'd'], ['d', 's', 'a'], ['q', 'w', 'e']]

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma, estarías pidiendo que el usuario ingrese una palabra `m` veces, convirtiendo cada una en una lista, para luego obtener cada caracter hasta el `n`-ésimo.

```
for i in range(m):
    palabras = input()
    guia = list(palabras)
    for j in range(n):
        matrix[i][j] = guia[j]
```